# Fixing Slow PYTHON Code: Given a list of word sorted in alphabetical order determine which words contain the given letters as a subsequence

Tags: python

> Given   a   list    of  words   sorted  in  alphabetical    order,  and     a   string  of
> required    letters,    find    and return  the list    of  words   that    contain letters as  a   subsequence.

My code works but is taking too long and times out. Can anyone recommend any changes to be made?

```
def words_with_letters(words, letters):
  def isSubSequence(str1, str2):
    len_str1 = len(str1)
    len_str2 = len(str2)
    index_str1 = 0  
    index_str2 = 0  
    # Traverse both str1 and str2
    while index_str1 < len_str1 and index_str2 < len_str2:
        # Compare current character of str2 with str1
        if str1[index_str1] == str2[index_str2]:
            # If matched, then move to next character in str1
            index_str1 = index_str1 + 1
        index_str2 = index_str2 + 1
    if index_str1 == len_str1:
      return True
    else:
      return False


  result = []
  for i in words:
    if isSubSequence(letters, i):
      result.append(i)
  return result
```

Comment: We have no idea what "test case #7" refers to, or what that test case's criteria are. If it doesn't matter, then just leave it out, since it's potentially going to confuse people to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the brief then it's as simple as this:-

```
result = []
words = ['hello', 'banana', 'cockroach', 'roadkill']
letters = 'ro'

for word in words:
  if letters in word:
    result.append(word)

print(result)
```

Comment: Well, the subsequence is different than substring. In subsequences the letters is not required to be adjacent in the original word. For example 'rm' is subsequence of 'roma'